# How to access local virtualhost with android device

Tags: android, apache2, virtualhost

i setup few virtualhosts on my laptop, and all of them are name based for example :

```
  www.example1.dev
  www.example2.dev
  ...
```

and i want to access them with my real android device using USB cable.
and im already conncted to same wifi network as well.

but everytime i try to access one of my virtualhost from my android device i get `address not found`
i also checked this question
[How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)
but its related to ip address while im using name based virtualhost

## edit 1 :

this is one of my virtual host setup that im trying to accessing it from my android device:

/etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/examplesite1.dev.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    <Directory /var/www/examplesite1>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    ServerName examplesite1.dev.com
    ServerAlias www.examplesite1.dev.com
    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/examplesite1


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

and /etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1   examplesite1.dev.com
192.168.250.1   examplesite1.dev.com
192.168.1.51    examplesite1.dev.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the local host via:

```
http://192.168.1.1/{{service end points}}
```

it will help you to access the localhost from your mobile

Comment: i already tried that and unfortunatley it doesnt work and i simply get 404 error

Comment: Did you check it on a browser with the default IP?

Comment: i checked it with the browser yeah, however i dont know what you mean by default IP

Comment: Http//127.1.0.0 default IP Address pointed to localhost. And one thing more mobile and local host must connected to same internet

Comment: im already connected to same internet as i mentioned in my question